# Regex multiple matches and $1, $2 variables (quick and easy!)

Tags: regex, solr

I need to extract numeric values from strings like "£17,000 - £35,000 dependent on experience"

```
([0-9]+k?[.,]?[0-9]+)
```

That string is just an example, i can have `17k` `17.000` `17` `17,000`, in every string there can be 0,1 or 2 numbers (not more than 2), they can be everywhere in the string, separated by anything else. I just need to extract them, put the first extracted in a place and the second in another.

I could come up with this, but it gives me two matches (don't mind the `k?[,.]`, it's correct), in the `$1` grouping. I need to have `17,000` in `$1` and `35,000` in `$2`, how can i accomplish this? I can also manage to use 2 different regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regex

With every opening round bracket you create a new capturing group. So to have a second capturing group `$2`, you need to match the second number with another part of your regex that is within brackets and of course you need to match the part between the to numbers.

```
([0-9]+k?[.,]?[0-9]+)\s*-\s*.*?([0-9]+k?[.,]?[0-9]+)
```

See [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2u3je)

But could be that Solr has regex functions that put all matches into an array, that would maybe be easier to use.

Comment: this is actually the best matcher, except i'm not always having a - between the numbers,but any character there.

Comment: @Samuele Mattiuzzo Then try just to delete `\s*-\s*` the `.*?` part will then cover every character till the next match is found.

Answer (score 0):

Match the entire dollar range with 2 capture groups rather than matching every dollar amount with one capture group:

```
([0-9]+k?[.,]?[0-9]+) - ([0-9]+k?[.,]?[0-9]+)
```

However, I'm worried (yeah, I'm minding it :p) about that regex as it will match some strange things:

```
182k,938 - 29.233333
```

will both be matched, it can definitely be improved if you can give more information on your input types.

Answer (score 0):

What about something along the lines of

```
[£]?([0-9]+k?[.,]?[0-9]+) - [£]([0-9]+k?[.,]?[0-9]+)
```

This should now give you two groups.

Edit: Might need to clean up the spaces too